Type hint a custom dictionary object as TypedDict
Is it possible to get the TypedDict values passed as a generic within a class to enable type hinting?
I have a dictionary where I would like to be able to get the type annotations from the passed generic TypeDict within the __getattr__.
Given this example. I want to get code completion and highlighting when using dot notation. Is this possible?
from typing import TypedDict


class MyDict[T](dict):
    def __init__(self, base_dict: T) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self._data = base_dict

    def __getattr__(self, item):
        dots = item.split(".")
        data = self._data
        for dot in dots:
            data = data.get(dot)
            if isinstance(data, dict):
                return MyDict(data)
            if data is None:
                raise ValueError("Key not found")

        return data


class TestDef(TypedDict):
    foo: int
    bar: str
    baz: dict[str, bool]


data_dict: TestDef = {
    "foo": 10,
    "bar": "bar",
    "baz": {"qux": True}
}

d = MyDict(data_dict)

v1 = d.foo
print(v1)
v2 = d.baz.qux
print(v2)



No. You can write a mypy plugin to make mypy understand this, but certainly not autocomplete and not something working across all type checkers.

Accessing dict values using dotted notation is a commonly asked question. However, if you want static typing to work, avoid this kind of dynamic evaluation.

If you're trying to use the "dot attribute" syntax, and want type checking on a dictionary, I would highly recommend using Pydantic. It's an external library that validates dict structures and then let's you access them with this syntax:
from pydantic import BaseModel

class SubDef(BaseModel):
    qux: bool

class TestDef(BaseModel):
    foo: int
    bar: str
    baz: SubDef


data_dict = {
    "foo": 10,
    "bar": "bar",
    "baz": {"qux": True}
}

d = TestDef.model_validate(data_dict)

v1 = d.foo
print(v1)
v2 = d.baz.qux
print(v2)

print(d.model_dump()) # Converts back to dict if needed

Hope this is useful!
